# Exercise 3.4 in Jaynes' Probability Theory

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am having trouble solving exercise 3.4 from E. T. Jaynes' Probability Theory: The Logic of Science.

There are M urns numbered 1 to M, and M balls, also numbered one to M, which are thrown into them, one in each urn. If the numbers of a ball and its urn are the same, we have a match. Show that the probability for at least one match is:
$$h = ∑_{k=1}^M{ \frac{(-1)^{(k+1)}}{k!} }$$

How do I solve it?

Comment: The more information you give about what you do understand about this problem, or about how far you have got by yourself, the more likely you are to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of finding the number of ways to do it with **no match** is the classical problem of counting [derangements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement). For the probability of no match one divides by $M!$.

The Wikipedia article linked to gives a good overview, and includes a proof.

The problem has also been asked and answered repeatedly on MSE.

Comment: Thank you, and I'm very sorry about repeating the question! I wasn't aware of the name "derangement" or the concept.

Comment: @PedroCarvalho: No problem! A vast majority of the problems on MSE yield to known results.

Answer (score 1):

It is a generalization of expression (2.82) in the book. If $M_i$ is a match in urn $i$, then the question reduces to finding $P(M_1+M_2+...+M_m)$, where $m$ is the total number of urns. Using the sum rule of probability
$P(M_1+M_2+...+M_m)=P(M_1)+P(M_2)+...+P(M_m) - P(M_1M_2)-P(M_1M_3) - ... - P(M_{m-1}M_m)+P(M_1M_2...M_m)$.

Given (3.7),(3.39) and (3.40), $P(M_i)=P(M_j), \forall$ $i$ and $j$, and so are $P(M_iM_j)$ and so on.
In  $P(M_1+M_2+...+M_m)$, there are $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}m\\1\end{array}\right)$ $P(M_i)$'s, $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}m\\2\end{array}\right)$ $P(M_iM_j)$'s, $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}m\\3\end{array}\right)$ $P(M_iM_jM_k)$'s, so on, and $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}m\\m\end{array}\right)$ $P(M_1M_2...M_m)$'s.

Ex. For $m=3$, we have $P(M_1+M_2+M_3)=P(M_1)+P(M_2)+P(M_3)- P(M_1M_2)-P(M_1M_3)-P(M_2M_3)+ P(M_1M_2M_3)$.

There are 3! 3-tuples, which are
(1,2,3)
(1,3,2)
(2,1,3)
(2,3,1)
(3,1,2)
(3,2,1).
$P(M_1)$=2/6, $P(M_2)$=2/6, $P(M_3)$=2/6. $P(M_2|M_1) = 1/2$, $P(M_3|M_1) = 1/2$, and $P(M_3|M_2) = 1/2$, and $P(M_3|M_1M_2) = 1$.

Using the product rule of probability,
$P(M_1+M_2+M_3)=3*2/6 - 3*2/6*1/2 + 1*2/6*1/2 = \sum_{k=1}^{m=3} (-1)^{k+1}/k!=2/3$.